# background image not showing up CSS

Tags: html, css

please help me find out why my background image is not showing up. The codes do create a div on the web page but the image just doesn't show up. I insert html img tag to see if the image works fine and it does work fine so i think it must be the CSS part that went wrong.

1. This is my html codes

   ```
    <section id="experience">
        <div class="experience-photo">


        </div>
        <div class="experience">
   <h2>In the process of understanding society</h2>

    <div>
    <div class="">
      <img src="Images /UBC.jpeg" alt="ubc">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a href="https://www.ubc.ca/">The University of British Columbia</a>
      <h3>B. S. in Sociology with minor in Business, class of 2020</h3>
      <h3>Vancouver,Canada</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
   ```
2. this is my CSS codes

   ```
    .experience-photo {
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url("images /Experience.JPG");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;

    }
   ```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Make sure your background is on a _visible_ element with _non-zero height and width_. URL paths are case-sensitive. Are you sure you have a space in your `images` or `Images` directory?

Comment: Path looks funky

Comment: Thank you @user4642212! it turned out the image was not saved in the CSS file.

Answer (score -1):

works

```css
 .experience-photo {
   height: 100vh;
   background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/6756/1*5yjpWuKh2tQFMlkFdQy-rA.jpeg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;

 }
```

```html
 <section id="experience">
     <div class="experience-photo">


     </div>
     <div class="experience">
<h2>In the process of understanding society</h2>

 <div>
 <div class="">
   <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/noQ19SshsZpB05KNJyifaxMYfmOGa_8_heMljhfFkhRclxDMqiw4aqFRiGeEDdil_qpG2DYMtUe-RQCf--kP5hDD0E2VYqeDU8tzbazfW7Ye4v5LhvANdRUh8hBhJh_o3_DRzk0eM0mnQ6-CaBvw" alt="ubc">
 </div>
 <div class="">
   <a href="https://www.ubc.ca/">The University of British Columbia</a>
   <h3>B. S. in Sociology with minor in Business, class of 2020</h3>
   <h3>Vancouver,Canada</h3>
   <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
     sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
     nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
     in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
   </p>
 </div>
```